# How to connect to another PC through different networks

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking

When I run both codes on my PC they work. However when I give my friend one of the code to connect with me it doesn't work. Were both on different networks.

I've tried using my Hostname on both. I also tried to use my local IP.

## Bottom code I use

```
import os
import socket


s = socket.socket()
port = 8079


s.bind(("My_Host_Name",port))
print("Scanning income connections")

s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()


print("Connected to:",addr)


while 1:
    #Sender
    command = input(str("Me: "))
    command = command.encode()
    conn.send(command)
    print("")



    #Reciever 
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    data = data.decode()
    print("Anonymous: "+data)
    print("")
```

## The bottom one is the one I give my friend

```
import os
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "My_Host_Name"
port = 8079



s.connect((host,port))

while 1:
    #Reciever
    data = s.recv(1024)
    data = data.decode()
    print("Anonymous: " + data)
    print("")


    #Sender
    command = input(str("Me: "))
    command = command.encode()
    s.send(command)
    print("")
```

I expect it to connect through different networks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your friend to connect, your server app needs to `bind()` to a local LAN IP/port of the PC it is running on, and then your client app needs to `connect()` to the public WAN IP/port of your network router, not the server's LAN IP/port.  Your router needs to be configured to port-forward connections from the WAN IP/port to the server's LAN IP/Port. If your router supports uPNP, you can setup that forwarding programmatically in your server code, otherwise you will have to configure it manually in the router's admin interface.

Comment: Ok I do understand clearly now. However I am alittle confused on how to obtain all of this. I do find my local LAN IP from ipconfig which is my IPV4. Then the port I find in the router's admin interface and the WAN IP/port? And if I do obtain all of this information how can I make sure when I use this into my code I can hash it or something so my friend does not figure out my WAN IP/port.

Comment: Yes, running `ipconfig` on the server PC will give you the LAN IP. You choose whatever port you want the server is listen on.  Enter those into the router port-forwarding config. The WAN IP, you can get from the router's config, or you can query an external site like `https://www.whatismyip.com`. The WAN Port, you choose. Why would you hide the WAN IP/Port from your friend? Your client needs them, give them to your friend so (s)he can enter them into the client on their PC. Otherwise, store them into a (encrypted?) file/string to load into the client and have it decrypt if needed.

Comment: For port as I can choose whatever I want it to be. Does that mean I can use any numbers? And if so do I use those same numbers for the other script for my friend to use. Or is it a spesific port from my router or PC that use to access internet?

Comment: @Mike your server can listen on any port number that is not in use, or reserved by the OS. Same with your router for forwarding. The forwarding port and the listening port do not need to be the same number. But whichever port you forward from, that is the port the client needs to connect to